# Chuppah by a Zivug Sheini (second marriage) and the "main" kinyan

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage, zivug-sheini

It seems that the prevalent minhag by a zivug sheini (second marriage) is to have the chuppah inside (as opposed to the minhag of (at least) the ashkanazim to have the chuppah outside.) What is the reason or makor that even for those that normally have the minhag to make the chuppah outside, that by a zivug sheini it should be done inside?

I have heard that a connection is made between getting married and the giving of the Torah where the luchos shnius weren't given b'kolos, therefore since a connection is made to marriage therefore by a zivug sheini also shouldn't be done so publicly. Is there any makor for this reason? Is this *the* reason for making the chuppah inside?

On the other hand I've heard that it doesn't matter where the chuppah is made, whether inside or out, so as long as it's close to the cheder yichud (private room where married couple go after the chuppah) since that is the "main" kinyan by a zivug sheini. Is this indeed the "main" kinyan (the cheder yichud) and if so is there a makor for this reasoning that the chuppah should be inside so as to be as close to the cheder yichud as possible? What matters if there is some more time spent walking from the chuppah to the cheder yichud?

Comment: cf OC 339:5 about the main Kinyan by a Zivug Sheni.

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct, thank you. However does this warrant having the chuppah being inside in order to be "as close" to the cheder yichud as possible? Or is it all "al tzad hayoser tov".

Comment: I've actually been to two Zivugei (?) Sheni where the Chuppah was outside, so I question your claim about the prevalent minhag.

Comment: @DoubleAA And I've been to 2 (one tonight!) that the chuppah was inside. But that the chuppah should be outside isn't a "din" and just an "inyun" ... The sephardim I believe always have inside? Or many do?

Comment: @DoubleAA I honestly think many do it inside now a days because of embarrassment. Maybe times these weddings are much smaller, held in smaller halls. In a city like Yerushalayim it would be obvious what is going on and some might feel uncomfortable with that.